# How do I get a selector on the specific span inside div in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

Assume I have the following:

```
<input type="text">
<div id="listofstuff">
    <div class="anitem">
        <span class="item name">Dog</span>
        <span class="itemdescription">AboutItem1</span>
    </div> 
    <div class="anitem">
        <span class="item name">Doodle Bird</span>
        <span class="itemdescription">AboutItem2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="anitem">
       <span class="item name">Cat</span>
       <span class="itemdescription">AboutItem3</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to use jQuery selectors to get the `<div>` (`.anitem`) that contains the `<span>` with the item name "Cat".

I thought it would be something like below, but it doesn't work.

```
$('#listofstuff').find('.anitem div span:contains("Cat")');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do with that selector?

Comment: Please provide the HTML you're trying to process using this jQuery snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `:has` pseudo-class to get an element by its descendants:

```
$('#listofstuff .anitem:has(span:contains("Cat"))')
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/XHjAX/)

Comment: Thats it! So what if I say had another div element nested within that span element that had "Siamese". Would it then be: $('#listofstuff .anitem:has(span div:contains("Siamese"))')?

Comment: @Teiviere: Yes. (You know, you *can* try it on the jsFiddle...)

Comment: @Teiviere: Remember my syntax (or others) will work too - I personally find mine easier to read, so have a play and use what you're most comfortable with (but accept this answer either way!)

Answer (score 2):

`$('.anitem').has('span:contains("Cat")')` might get you closer

Comment: Certainly no shortage of ways to do this in jQuery! Any of these should work fine. I think @minitech was first to answer so probably should get the points ;)

Comment: I had it wrong, though, and edited after you answered. So +1.

Comment: Hah, yes, I did see that but thought I'd let it slide ;)

Answer (score 1):

If not the fastest, it's the most sensible.

```
$('#listofstuff span:contains("Cat")').parent();
```

---

### [*demo*](http://jsfiddle.net/y56Rb/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#listofstuff').find('div.anitem:has(span:contains("Cat"))')
```